decrease space between code block and text
I have a org-mode beamer slide, I would like to decrease the vertical space between the code block and text area.
full code:
#+startup: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer

#+BEAMER_FONT_THEME: structurebold
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [aspectratio=169]
#+options: toc:nil
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz} 
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{background}{
#+BEAMER_HEADER:     \begin{tikzpicture}
#+BEAMER_HEADER:         %\shade[left color=blue,right color=red] (0,0) rectangle(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
#+BEAMER_HEADER:         \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=10pt,outer sep=0pt] (m) at (0,15cm) {Hi};
#+BEAMER_HEADER:         \draw[line width=.5] ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=5pt]m.south) -- ++(-13.5cm,0);
#+BEAMER_HEADER:     \end{tikzpicture}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: }

#+BEAMER_HEADER: \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
#+BEAMER_HEADER:     \usebeamerfont{footline}%
#+BEAMER_HEADER:     \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
#+BEAMER_HEADER:     %\hspace{1em}%
#+BEAMER_HEADER:     \insertdate\hspace{14.5cm}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
#+BEAMER_HEADER: }

#+LATEX_HEADER:   \lstset{
#+LATEX_HEADER:     language=python,
#+LATEX_HEADER:     basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont,
#+LATEX_HEADER:     backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray!50},
#+LATEX_HEADER:     commentstyle=\bfseries,
#+LATEX_HEADER:     escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}
#+LATEX_HEADER:   }

#+AUTHOR: 
#+DATE: 
#+DATE: 5/10/24
* Hello beamer

** 1. topic 1
- line 1
  code bloack start
#+begin_src python
i = 0
for i in range(0,10):
    print(i)
#+end_src
code block end
-- line 2


Output:


Please include the intermediate .tex file in your question.

As mentioned here: specify aboveskip=0pt inside the \lstset. Play with the value as per your requirements.
